# Typescript generics: pass a function and its parameters to a wrapper function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to figure out a type safe way to pass the function and its parameters (whatever is the number of parameters) to another wrapper function in typescript. What I want to achieve is following:

```
const myFunc1 = () => {...};
wrapper(myFunc1);

const myFunc2 = (a: string) => {...};
wrapper(myFunc2, 'hello');

const myFunc3 = (a: string, b: number) => {...};
wrapper(myFunc3, 'hello', 10);
```

Here is my attempt:

```
function wrapper<A extends (...params: B[]) => any, B extends any>(x: A, ...y: B[]) {}
```

Comment: Use the `Parameters` and `ReturnType` utilities: https://tsplay.dev/w6ppEm

Comment: It works! Answer the question and I will give you +1 right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility on `y`:

```
function wrapper<A extends (...params: any[]) => any>(x: A, ...y: Parameters<A>) {
```

You can also annotate the return type as the return type of `A` using the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility:

```
function wrapper<A extends (...params: any[]) => any>(x: A, ...y: Parameters<A>): ReturnType<A> {
    return x.call(undefined, ...y);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczAIwwLwwBQCUOAfDAN4C+A3ALABQA7gE4CGADmwKZN6KroYCtOvVCRYfNMABMOfCwBcMaEwCWYAOZFspSsObsuPSemkAaGAHIAFpwA2dkJaH1R4aPGRSAzHLyLlKDVNCwAjJTAUOFDubV1qegMObl4vdG8LG3tHSwsMAAYXEToAMykoVXAYJKMAHgBBGE4ADyhOMAATCHwAOj62FlY4CCUWMAQAbQBdOJgxhGI8ZqV6iz6ehCUABUGWOE42pggG4gIlACUDlCYwABUELhPyehhXmCYrm5hmnuAWBzwaA6nBK6k4HTWfQQRQo9CAA)